# Corda : Is it possible to have a single node network?

Tags: corda

Can there be just a single node (not even a notary) in the corda n/w?
If yes, can the single node execute corda flows that will have the single node both as sender and receiver?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Theoretically Yes, you could have a single node that serves both as a transacting party as well as a notary. For executing flows yes it can self-issue and consume states as well.

Practically, I do not see any implication of such a network, why use DLT for such use-case.